# SMART data of SanDisk Extreme Pro

Tags: ssd, data, smart

I have RHEL 6.8 with smartmontool 5.43 on Dell OptiPlex 9020 with SanDisk Extreme Pro 240 GB SSD as OS disk used for quite disk i/o intensive work. I am concerned about durability of SSD. After one month of usage, I try to use smartctl the drive which reports data, much of which does not make much sense, for example:

```
- ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST   RAW_VALUE 
- 233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100     2610 
- 241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0030   253   253     954 
- 242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0030   253   253     54
```

Raw value of Media_Wearout_Indicator is way to high and Total LBA read/written are way too low. How should I interpret these numbers and avoid the risk of losing the drive & data?

Comment: That drive is fine. According to the attribute description, 100 is the best and starting normalized value, and 1 is the worst: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_attributes_of_Intel_SSDs. As far as losing data, you should always have backups, regardless of drive health.

Comment: Is there any way to interpret the RAW_VALUEs?

Comment: Turns out that the smartmontools v5.43 shipped with RHEL 6 is 5 years old. Got the v6.5 from sourceforge.net, now I see:

<pre>
233 Total_NAND_Writes_GiB   0x0032   100   100   9860
241 Total_Writes_GiB        0x0030   253   253   1853
</pre>

I still don't understand the above two attributes. I did not find the definition of these attributes but the wording indicates that #241 is number of GB sent to SSD for writing, #233 is number of GB actually written to media. If so, one would normally expect #241 value to be larger than #233, that too by a small margin.